# How to create nested rows collapse in table with same column using knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to create table like below picture using knockout js dynamically in which if there is child node then collapse 
[image]

Comment: Can you show what have you tried? Any reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [TreeGrid](http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/%20TreeGrid) jQuery plugin.  It's rather simple to use.  We put our data in an HTML `table` and then assign each row an treegrid id and optionally a treegrid parent id.  Here is a [basic example](http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/examples/example-basic.html) from the site...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the treegrid when the document is loaded
    $(function() {
        $('.tree').treegrid();
    });
</script>

<table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
        <td>Root node</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
        <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All we need to do to mimic your example is to replace "hard-coded" data with knockout bindings.  I've constructed a simple view model that contains an array of account objects.  I didn't include all the data or columns, but I've included enough to get you started in the right direction.

```js
$(function() {
  var viewModel = {};

  viewModel.accounts = [
    {name: 'Travel', type: 'Expenses', glCode: '50000', treegrid: '1', treegridParent: null},
    {name: 'Airfare', type: 'Expenses', glCode: '50010', treegrid: '2', treegridParent: '1'},
    {name: 'Lodging', type: 'Expenses', glCode: '50011', treegrid: '3', treegridParent: '1'},
    {name: 'Meals & Entertainment', type: 'Expenses', glCode: '50030', treegrid: '4', treegridParent: '1'},
    {name: 'Account Receiveable', type: 'Income', glCode: '40910', treegrid: '5', treegridParent: null},
    {name: 'Sales of Items', type: 'Income', glCode: '40819', treegrid: '6', treegridParent: '5'},
    {name: 'Sales on Web', type: 'Income', glCode: '40111', treegrid: '7', treegridParent: '5'},
    {name: 'Website #1', type: 'Income', glCode: '40661', treegrid: '8', treegridParent: '7'},
    {name: 'Website #2', type: 'Income', glCode: '40151', treegrid: '9', treegridParent: '7'},
  ];

  viewModel.getTreegridClass = function(item) {
    var className = '';
    if (item.treegrid)
      className += 'treegrid-' + item.treegrid;
    if (item.treegridParent)
      className += ' treegrid-parent-' + item.treegridParent;
    return className;
  }

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  $('.tree').treegrid();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/css/jquery.treegrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>

<table class="tree">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Name</th><th>Account Type</th><th>GL Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: accounts">
    <tr data-bind="attr: {class: $root.getTreegridClass($data)}">
      <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.type"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.glCode"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should first let OP to provide some reference of effort.

Comment: Thanks @Aron It really helpful